# Selenium Webdriver creating 2 sessions of chrome browser

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium

I am using a key-word driven framework. While calling the Chrome driver, its starting 2 instances of Chrome.

```
public static void navigate_toChrome(String fURL){
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:/Resources/chromedriver.exe");
    mD= new ChromeDriver();
    mD.navigate().to(fURL);
    mD.manage().window().maximize();
    Capabilities caps = ((RemoteWebDriver) mD).getCapabilities();
    String browserName = caps.getBrowserName();
    String browserVersion = caps.getVersion();
    System.out.println(browserName+" "+browserVersion);
}
```

Comment: Your method `navigate_toChrome`  doesn't do just that, it does multiple things.  Thats part of the problem as well.

Answer (score 0):

Hi i think you have initiated your WebDriver like below

```
public WebDriver  mD ;
or
public WebDriver  mD = null;
```

please change it to

```
public static WebDriver  mD ;
    or
public static WebDriver  mD = null;
```

It will stop starting 2 instances of Chrome. Hope this helps you

Comment: We have used public static WebDriver myD;